# If all the real parts of the eigenvalues are negative, then indeed $e^{tA}→0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-decomposition

Is there a short proof to show if all the real parts of the eigenvalues are negative, then indeed $e^{tA}→0$?

Also I am wondering if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} ||e^{At}||=0 \iff $ the real parts of all eigenvalues are LESS than 0 or can we have equal to 0 if the algabric and geometric multiplicities are the same?

Comment: $\|e^{tA}\|\to 0$ is the same as saying $e^{tA}\to 0$. If alg. and geom. multis are all equal, then the matrix is diagonalizable. What happens then when one of the eigenvalues is purely imaginary?

Comment: @amsmath I  think if one is purely imaginary then the norm doesn't go to zero anymore... but I am not sure

Comment: @Math4LifeThis is correct.

Comment: In the general case, you will have to work with the Jordan form. You have $A = SJS^{-1}$ with an invertible $S$ and the Jordan form $J$. Now, $e^{tA} = Se^{tJ}S^{-1} = Se^{tJ_1}e^{itJ_2}S^{-1}$, where $J = J_1 + iJ_2$. Note that $J_2$ is diagonal so that $e^{itJ_2}$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries lying on the unit circle. In particular, it is bounded. You will have to see how $e^{tJ_1}$ looks like.

Comment: @amsmath Could I say $e^{Jt}=e^{tD}e^{tN}$ where D is the diagonal of J and N is nilpotent? Then $e^{tD}e^{tN}=e^{uD}e^{tN}$ where $u=a+bi$ is an eigenvalue then $e^{(a+bi)t}e^{tN}$ shows that $e^{at}$ for negative a causes the term to go to 0 as t goes to infinity?

Comment: That is also possible - maybe even better than my approach. Sure, the diagonal of $e^{tD}$ tends to zero, hence so does $e^{tD}$. Now, it only remains to show that $e^{tN}$ is bounded. EDIT: Ah, and before you write $e^{tD+tN} = e^{tD}e^{tN}$ you will have to make sure that $D$ and $N$ commute.

Comment: awesome thank you so much for the help. Your approach made me think of that :)?

Comment: You're welcome. And note my edit.

Comment: @amsmath:  $e^{Nt}$ isn't bounded but since $e^{Dt} \to 0$ exponentially, i dominates the polynomial $e^{Nt}$ and so $e^{(D + N)t} \to 0$ etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @RobertLewis Oh, yes, indeed. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the shortest I could find:

Let $ A = P J P^{-1} $ be the Jordan decomposition of A. Then $ e^{tA} = e^{t P J P^{-1}} = P e^{tJ} P^{-1} $.

Since $J$ is a block diagonal matrix, $e^J$ is also a block diagonal matrix and each of its blocks is the exponential of a block of $J$.

Hence $ \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^{tA} = 0 \iff $ for each Jordan block $B$, $ \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^tB = 0 $.

A Jordan block $B$ has the form
$$ B(m,n)=
\begin{cases} 
\lambda &, n = m \\
1 &, n = m + 1  \\
0
\end{cases} $$

where $ \lambda = a + ib $ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

So
$$ e^B(m,n)=
\begin{cases} 
\frac{t^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} e^{\lambda t} &, m \le n \\
0
\end{cases} $$

Therefore $ \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^{tB} = 0 \iff \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^{\lambda t} = 0 $.

As $e^{i b t}$ is continuous and periodic, and consequently bounded
$$ \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^{\lambda t} = \lim_\limits{t \to \infty} e^{a t} e^{i b t} = 0 \iff a < 0 $$

Thus we can conlude that
$$ \lim_\limits{t \to\infty} ||e^{At}||=0 \iff \eta(A) < 0 $$
where $ \eta(A) $ is the [spectral abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_abscissa) of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure this answer makes the cut in terms of *shortness*; I'll have to credit mucciolo on that score.  Having said this, I offer the following, in which I have tried to gather most of the details together in one single writ, which is I think reasonably thorough and, hopefully, *not too long*.

The problem question indeed expresses a widely used fact which, despite its ubiquity of application, is not generally understood in detail.

Look first at a single Jordan block $B$ of size $b$.  It is a $b \times b$ matrix of the form

$B = \lambda I + N, \tag 1$

where

$N^b = 0 \tag 2$

but

$N^{b - 1} \ne 0. \tag 3$

It is easy to compute

$e^{Bt} = e^{(\lambda I + N)t}; \tag 4$

since $IN = NI$ we may maneuver $e^{\lambda I t}$ and $e^{Nt}$ exactly as if $\lambda I$ and $N$ were ordinary numbers (i.e. $1 \times 1$ matrices) as far as multiplication is concerned, and thus

$e^{(\lambda I + N)t} = e^{\lambda I t}e^{Nt} = (e^{\lambda t} I)e^{Nt} = e^{\lambda t}e^{Nt}, \tag 5$

where

$e^{\lambda I t} = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(\lambda I t)^n}{n!} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}I^n = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}I = e^{\lambda t}I; \tag 6$

by (2) and (3) we have

$e^{Nt} = \displaystyle \sum_0^{b - 1} \dfrac{N^n}{n!}t^n, \tag 7$

the entries of which are polynomials in $t$ of degree at most $b - 1$.  If we now write

$\lambda = \Re(\lambda) + i \Im(\lambda), \tag 8$

we find

$e^{\lambda t} = e^{\Re(\lambda) t} e^{\Im(\lambda) t}, \tag 9$

whence

$e^{Bt} = e^{(\lambda I + N)t} = e^{\lambda t}e^{Nt} = e^{\Re(\lambda)t} e^{\Im(\lambda)t}e^{Nt}, \tag{10}$

so

$\Vert e^{Bt} \Vert = \Vert e^{\Re(\lambda)t} e^{\Im(\lambda)t}e^{Nt} \Vert = \vert e^{\Re(\lambda)t} \vert \vert  e^{\Im(\lambda)t} \vert \Vert e^{Nt} \Vert =  e^{\Re(\lambda)t}\Vert e^{Nt} \Vert , \tag{11}$

and by (7),

$\Vert e^{Nt} \Vert = \Vert \displaystyle \sum_0^{b - 1} \dfrac{(Nt)^n}{n!} \Vert \le \sum_0^{b - 1} \dfrac{\Vert N \Vert^n t^n}{n!}, \tag{12}$

so (11) and (12) yield

$\Vert e^{Bt} \Vert \le e^{\Re(\lambda) t} (\displaystyle \sum_0^{b - 1} \dfrac{\Vert N \Vert^n t^n}{n!}); \tag{13}$

with $\Re(\lambda) < 0$ the exponential on the right of (13) dominates the growth of the polynomial and thus

$\Vert e^{Bt} \Vert \le e^{\Re(\lambda) t} (\displaystyle \sum_0^{b - 1} \dfrac{\Vert N \Vert^n t^n}{n!}) \to 0 \; \text{as} \; t \to \infty. \tag{14}$

(14) binds for any Jordan block $B(\lambda)$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\Re(\lambda) < 0$:

$\Vert e^{B(\lambda) t} \Vert \to 0 \; \text{as} \; t \to 0; \tag{15}$

if now $A$ is in Jordan cannonical form and has $k$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i$,$1 \le i \le k$, each of which is associated with a Jordan block $B(\lambda_i)$, so that $A$ may be written in block diagonal form as

$A = \text{diag}(B(\lambda_1), B(\lambda_2), \ldots, B(\lambda_l), \ldots, B(\lambda_{k - 1}), B(\lambda_k))$
$= \begin{bmatrix} B(\lambda_1) & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots &  \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & B(\lambda_2) & 0 & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & 0 & B(\lambda_l) & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & B(\lambda_{k - 1}) & 0 \\ 0 &  0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 0 & B(\lambda_k) \end{bmatrix}; \tag{16}$

it follows that

$e^{At} = \text{diag}(e^{B(\lambda_1) t}, e^{B(\lambda_2) t}, \ldots, e^{B(\lambda_l) t}, \ldots, e^{B(\lambda_{k - 1}) t}, e^{B(\lambda_k) t}); \tag{17}$

if we assume $\Re(\lambda_i) < 0$ for each $\lambda_i$ occurring in (17), then it follows from (14)-(15) that $\Vert e^{B(\lambda_i) t} \Vert \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ for each $i$; thus

$A(t) \to 0, \tag{18}$

which in fact holds if and only if

$\Vert A(t) \Vert \to 0. \tag{19}$

We may in fact derive bounds for $\Vert A(t) \Vert$ in terms of the $\Vert e^{B(\lambda_i) t} \Vert$ as follows:

Suppose the block diagonal matrix

$M = \text{diag}(L_1, L_2, \ldots, L_m) \tag{20}$

acts in the usual manner as an operator on $\Bbb C^{\text{size}(M)}$, which is equipped with the usual hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_M$ and norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_M = \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle^{1/2}_M$; we note that $M$ may be written as a sum

$M = \text{diag}(L_1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0) + \text{diag}(0, L_2, 0, \ldots, 0) + \ldots + \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_m)$
$= \displaystyle \sum_1^m \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0); \tag{21}$

then for any vector $x \in \Bbb C^{\text{size}(M)}$,

$Mx = \displaystyle \sum_1^m \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x, \tag{22}$

whence

$\Vert Mx \Vert_M = \displaystyle \Vert \sum_1^m \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M \le \sum_1^m \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M; \tag{23}$

also,

$\Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M \le \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0) \Vert_M \Vert x \Vert_M. \tag{24}$

Now

$\Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0) \Vert_M = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1}  \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M, \tag{25}$

and we note that the range of $\text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)$ lies in a $\text{size}(L_i)$-dimensional subspace $M_i \cong \Bbb C^{\text{size}(M_i)}$ of $\Bbb C^{\text{size}(M)}$; as we denote the inner product and norm on $M$ by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_M$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_M$, respectively so we denote those induced on $M_i$ by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_i$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_i$, we have

$\Vert \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M^2$
$= \langle \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x, \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \rangle_M$
$= \langle L_i x_i, L_i x_i \rangle_i =\Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i^2, \tag{26}$

where $x_i$ is the component of $x$ in the subspace $M_i$ of $M = \Bbb C^{\text{size}(M)}$ corresponding to the block $L_i$.  From (26)

$\Vert \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M = \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i, \tag{27}$

thus

$\sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i, \tag{28}$

and

$\sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i = \sup_{\Vert x_i \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i, \tag{29}$

which holds by virtue of the fact that $L_i:M_i \to M_i$, so that components $x_j \in M_j$ of $x$ in the subspaces $M_j$ normal to $M_i$ make zero contribution to $\sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i$; thus we may without loss of generality restrict $x$ to $M_i$, whence (29) binds.  Therefore, by (28) and (29),

$\sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert \text{diag}(0,  0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M = \sup_{\Vert x_i \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i; \tag{30}$

from (25),

$\Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0) \Vert_M = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1}  \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M$
$= \sup_{\Vert x_i \Vert = 1} \Vert L_i x_i \Vert_i = \Vert L_i \Vert_i, \tag{31}$

and therefore (23), with the aid of (24) and (31) yields

$\Vert Mx \Vert_M = \displaystyle \Vert \sum_1^m \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M \le \sum_1^m \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0)x \Vert_M$
$\le \displaystyle \sum_1^m \Vert \text{diag}(0, 0, \ldots, L_i, 0, \ldots, 0) \Vert_M \Vert x \Vert_M = \sum_1^m \Vert L_i \Vert_i \Vert x \Vert_M = (\sum_1^m \Vert L_i \Vert_i)\Vert x \Vert_M, \tag{32}$

which shows that

$\Vert M \Vert_M \le \displaystyle \sum_1^m \Vert L_i \Vert_i. \tag{33}$

If we acknowledge that all the apparatus of the subscripts ${}_M$ and ${}_i$ etc. were introduced merely to track the various inner products and norms invoked in the preceding discussion, and to distinguish them one from another, and that such an *explicit* notation is already *implicit* in the matrics $M$, $L_i$ and *their* norms etc.,  we may drop the subscripts and resort to the greatly simplified expression

$\Vert M \Vert \le \displaystyle \sum_1^m \Vert L_i \Vert, \tag{34}$

where it is understood that the norms are taken with respect to the  subspaces on which $M$ and the $L_i$ act.

We may apply (33) to (17) and conclude that

$\Vert e^{At} \Vert \le \displaystyle \sum_1^k \Vert e^{B(\lambda_i)} \Vert, \tag{34}$

and since each $\Vert e^{B(\lambda_i)} \Vert \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, it follows that

$\Vert e^{At} \Vert \to 0 \; \text{as} \; t \to \infty \tag{35}$

as well.  Hence, also, $e^{A t} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

It has been shown above that the negativity of the real parts of all eigenvalues is sufficient for $\Vert e^{At} \Vert \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.  Going the other way, if there is some $\lambda_i$ with $\Re(\lambda_i) \ge 0$, from (11) we see that

$\Vert e^{B(\lambda_i)t} \Vert =  e^{\Re(\lambda_i)t}\Vert e^{N_it} \Vert, \tag{36}$

where $B(\lambda_i) = \lambda_i I + N_i$ as in (1)-(15); then since $N_i^{b_i} = 0$ for some $b_i \in \Bbb N$, i.e., since $N_i$ is nilpotent, $e^{N_i t}$ is a polynomial in $t$, and as such, if it is not constant, which happens only when $N_i = 0$ so that $e^{N_i t} = I$ and hence $\Vert e^{N_i t} \Vert = 1$,   we have $\Vert e^{N_i t} \Vert \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.  In any event, whether $e^{N_i t}$ is constant  or not, when $\Re(\lambda_i) \ge 0$ the exponential $e^{\lambda_i t}$ is bounded below by $1$ as $t \to \infty$, forcing $\Vert e^{B(\lambda_i) t} \Vert \ge \Vert e^{N_i t} \Vert \not \to 0$ as well. Then $\Vert e^{A t} \Vert \not \to 0$ on the subspace corresponding to $B(\lambda_i)$, and this is sufficient to validate the claim $\Vert e^{A t} \Vert \not \to 0$ in general.

We have now established that

$[\forall i \;  \Re(\lambda_i ) < 0] \Longleftrightarrow [\Vert e^{A t} \Vert \to 0] \Longleftrightarrow  [e^{A t} \to 0] \tag{37}$

for matrices $A$ in Jordan cannonical form; but since *any* matrix $M$ may be written

$M = EAE^{-1} \tag{38}$

for some such $A$ with the same eigenvalues as $M$, and then

$e^{M t} = Ee^{A t} E^{-1}, \tag{39}$

it follows that

$[\forall i \;  \Re(\lambda_i ) < 0] \Longleftrightarrow [\Vert e^{M t} \Vert \to 0] \Longleftrightarrow  [e^{M t} \to 0] . \tag{40}$

Answer (score 0):

If $Av = \lambda v$ then $e^{tA}v = e^{t\lambda}v$.
Let $\lambda = a + ib$. Then $|e^{t\lambda}| = e^{t a}$.

Comment: So? This only proves the claim for diagonalizable matrices.